# How to clone SVN tags to GIT using tag name

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

I am currently working on migrating the SVN repository contents to GIT including trunk and tags. Strangely, i have hundreds of tags as below.

```
USERA-23.1.1
USERA-23.1.2
USERA-23.1.3
USERB-23.1.1
USERB-23.1.2
USERB-23.1.3
USERB-23.1.4
USERC-23.1.1
USERC-23.1.2
```

From the above list, i only want the latest 2 tags to be migrated for all users like below.

```
USERA-23.1.2
USERA-23.1.3
USERB-23.1.3
USERB-23.1.4
USERC-23.1.1
USERC-23.1.2
```

I tried giving the manual naming convention as below but i did not succeed.

```
git svn clone --tags='USERA-23.1.2' https://svnrepo/svn/userpackage/ testfolder
```

Is there anyway i can fetch the latest 2 versions of tags by using the naming convention.